# Is Kell Maresh in "Shades of Magic" named after "Mistborn" characters?

Tags: mistborn, shades-of-magic

In V.E. Schwab's *Shades of Magic* series (2017), the protagonist is named Kell Maresh.

I just recently finished reading the *Mistborn: The Final Empire* (2006), by Brandon Sanderson. In this book, two of the most important characters are brothers named Kelsier (who goes by the nickname Kell) and Marsh.

This seems unlikely to be a coincidence. Has V.E. Schwab admitted to being a Brandon Sanderson fan, or otherwise discussed the origins of Kell's name?

Comment: I notice these kinds of similarities all the time. :) For example, I was wondering about Robert Jackson Bennett's *Foundryside*, and references to LeGuin, Hobb and a few others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to her statement on Goodreads, no.  She says that she didn't read Mistborn until 2015.  https://www.goodreads.com/questions/407452-did-you-name-kell-after-kell-from

Comment: Wow, thanks for finding that! You have to admit it's a weird coincidence.

Comment: She also says somewhere that she didn't realize Alucard was Dracula backwards.  She just heard it somewhere else and thought it was a cool name.